# Reverse works in JSFiddle but not in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, maps, reverse-geocoding

I need help...

This code works in JSFiddle but not in the html file.
What am I missing?

Note:
APY key to JSFiddle: 6dc7fb95a3b246cfa0f3bcef5ce9ed9a

My APY Key: 5c449efbc0a0440792ed93038f997f7f

My Code:

```html
    <html>
    <head>

        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"
        ></script>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css"
        />
        <style>
        html,
        body,
        .main {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
        }

        .main {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
        }

        .address-line {
          padding: 10px;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          max-width: 200px;
        }

        #address {
          padding: 5px 10px;
          flex: 1;
          margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .results {
          padding: 10px;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          max-width: 200px;
        }

        .status {
          padding: 10px;
        }

        #my-map {
          flex: 1;
        }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="main">
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="address-line">
            <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Coordenadas">
            <br>
            <button onclick="geocodeAddress()">Search</button>
          </div>
          <div class="results">
            <input id="street" type="text" readonly />
            <input id="postcode" type="text" readonly />
            <input id="city" type="text" readonly />
            <input id="country" type="text" readonly />
          </div>
          <div class="status">
            <span id="status">Insert Coords... and "Search"</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="my-map"></div>
      </div>

        Latitude:<input type="text" name="fname" id="lat"><br>
        Longitude:<input type="text" name="lname" id="lng"><br>

        <table id="table" border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Latitude</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>38.714224,-7.961452</td>
            <td>48.150036, 11.57539</td>
     
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>48.150036, 11.57539</td>
            <td>38.1504, 11.5734</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>38.1504, 11.5734</td>
            <td>38.714224,-7.961452</td>

          </tr>
        </table>

        <script>
          var table = document.getElementById('table');

          for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
              //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
              document.getElementById("address").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
              document.getElementById("lng").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;

            };
          }
          // Create a Leaflet map
          const map = L.map('my-map').setView([48.1500327, 11.5753989], 10);
          // Marker to save the position of found address
          let marker;

            // The API Key provided is restricted to JSFiddle website
            // Get your own API Key on https://myprojects.geoapify.com ....6dc7fb95a3b246cfa0f3bcef5ce9ed9a
            const myAPIKey = "5c449efbc0a0440792ed93038f997f7f";

          // Retina displays require different mat tiles quality
          const isRetina = L.Browser.retina;
          const baseUrl = "https://maps.geoapify.com/v1/tile/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apiKey={apiKey}";
          const retinaUrl = "https://maps.geoapify.com/v1/tile/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?apiKey={apiKey}";

          // add Geoapify attribution
          map.attributionControl.setPrefix('Powered by <a href="https://www.geoapify.com/" target="_blank">Geoapify</a>')

          // Add map tiles layer. Set 20 as the maximal zoom and provide map data attribution.
          L.tileLayer(isRetina ? retinaUrl : baseUrl, {
            attribution: '<a href="https://openmaptiles.org/" target="_blank">© OpenMapTiles</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            apiKey: myAPIKey,
            maxZoom: 20,
            id: 'osm-bright',
          }).addTo(map);

          // move zoom controls to bottom right
          map.zoomControl.remove();
          L.control.zoom({
            position: 'bottomright'
          }).addTo(map);

          function geocodeAddress() {
            const address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            if (!address || address.length < 3) {
              document.getElementById("status").textContent = "The address string is too short. Enter at least three symbols";

              return;
            }

            if (marker) {
              marker.remove();
            }

            const geocodingUrl = `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=${encodeURIComponent(address)}&apiKey=${myAPIKey}`;

            // call Geocoding API - https://www.geoapify.com/geocoding-api
            fetch(geocodingUrl).then(result => result.json())
              .then(featureCollection => {
                if (featureCollection.features.length === 0) {
                  document.getElementById("status").textContent = "The address is not found";
                  return;
                }

                const foundAddress = featureCollection.features[0];

                document.getElementById("street").value = foundAddress.properties.street || '';
                document.getElementById("postcode").value = foundAddress.properties.postcode || '';
                document.getElementById("city").value = foundAddress.properties.city || '';

                document.getElementById("country").value = foundAddress.properties.country || '';

                document.getElementById("status").textContent = `Found address: ${foundAddress.properties.formatted}`;
marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(foundAddress.properties.lat, foundAddress.properties.lon)).addTo(map);
                map.panTo(new L.LatLng(foundAddress.properties.lat, foundAddress.properties.lon)); 
              });
          }

        </script>
        
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: What do you expect happens? What happens instead? Any errors? Any specific steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It was supposed to locate on the map and indicate the address below the form....

In JSFiddle I click on the table with the coordinates and then find them on the search button.... It is supposed to show the location on the map and the address where it is located